# List available files in the S3 bucket in spring batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to build logic to check the availability of the files in the S3 bucket. If the files are there , I will download it for the processing and if it's not there then I would like to wait for the file for sometime.

I am able to get the files using below code but even though the files are available the first occurrence is not able to find and going into the else part. I would like to avoid it because once I implement the wait logic and wait for the files to arrive after 3 minutes, it will pickup the files after 3 minutes even though the files would still be available.

```
request = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(s3BucketName).withPrefix("4275/input/");
        result = s3client.listObjectsV2(request);

        LOGGER.info("Total number of files in the S3 bucket {0} ", result.getKeyCount());

        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : result.getObjectSummaries()) {
            if (objectSummary.getKey().endsWith("csv")) {
                System.out.printf(" - %s (size: %d)\n", objectSummary.getKey(), objectSummary.getSize());

            } else {
                // wait for the availability of file
                LOGGER.info("the file is not available");
            }
        }
```

**Output :**

```
2021-04-14 10:13:18.437  INFO 1032 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.S.BatchConfig.S3BucketConfig         : the file is not available <-- first occurrence of loop
 - 4275/input/75sample.csv (size: 239505)
 - 4275/input/275sample.csv (size: 239505)
```

Comment: You would have to relist the objects every time.  However, if you're hosting your site in AWS you can have a Lambda that is called when a new CSV file is added with a particular prefix.

Comment: There is nothing specific to Spring Batch in this question, so I'm removing the `spring-batch` tag.